# How to rewrite url in php with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help for PHP
My url is like this..............

```
http://localhost/cabs/airport.php?loc=majestic
```

and i want to change it like this.......

```
http://localhost/cabs/airport/loc/majestic
```

OR

```
http://localhost/cabs/airport/majestic
```

My code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule airport-loc-(.*).htm$ airport.php?loc=$1
```

Any one please help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^airport/(.*) ./cabs/airport.php?loc=$1
```

Comment: No need to put scheme and host name you are not redirecting.

Comment: Thanks updated based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Hope it will fix your issue.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/?cabs/airport/([^.]+)$ /cabs/airport.php?loc=majestic
```

updated

Comment: Your rule is incomplete btw, url not found error will be there and there is no L flag to stop processing and also ask op that where is he applying the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it.
But,only one use `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

#### Letter only work (airport.php?loc='Abc')

```
RewriteRule ^/?airport/([A-Z]+)$ airport.php?loc=$1 [NC,L]
```

#### Both number and letter work(airport.php?loc='123Abc')

```
RewriteRule ^/?airport/([0-9A-Z]+)$ airport.php?loc=$1 [NC,L]
```

#### Number only work(airport.php?loc='123')

```
RewriteRule ^/?airport/([0-9]+)$ airport.php?loc=$1 [NC,L]
```

Url must be like:

```
http://localhost/cabs/airport/majestic
```

Comment: Please you use only one RewriteRule for it.